# Inertia.js & Typescript: Argument type {} & InertiaFormProps{} is not assignable to parameter type Partial<VisitOptions> | undefined

Tags: typescript, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs, laravel-breeze

I created an empty Laravel project and installed Laravel Breeze with Typescript support.

Now when I create a form (with `useForm()`) and I use the `.post()` method and I use one of the options (e.g. `onFinish: () =>`) I get the following error:

> Argument type {onFinish: () => {password: string,
> password_confirmation: string, name: string, email: string} &
> InertiaFormProps<{password: string, password_confirmation: string,
> name: string, email: string}>} is not assignable to parameter type
> Partial | undefined

[image]

When I hover it in my editor it suggests to add all the members. Does this has something to do with Typescript or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the arrow function with a `{}` so it's of the form `functionName: () => {...}`. Your code is of the form `functionName: () => ...`

In your code, change `onFinish` to

```
onFinish() => {   //note the curly here 
     form.reset(...)
}
```

My understanding is that if you omit the {} then the arrow function has a **concise body**, which consists solely of a single expression whose result will implicitly become the return value of the function, and this `return` value may be causing the issue.

But, tbh, I'm not sure why yours doesn't work but the `{}` does.